solana localnet - Error while upgrading a program loaded at genesis using `solana-test-validator`?
Is it possible to redeploy a program if it was loaded at genesis (specifically on solana-test-validator)?
Error while upgrading a program loaded at genesis
While doing some testing, I am experiencing the following:

build program
launch test validator, reset the ledger, and load the program at genesis

make sure the upgrade authority is your local keypair


attempt to deploy that same program to the same address as before
get an error (listed below)

However, if the program is NOT loaded at genesis of solana-test-validator, the program initial deploy and upgrade work fine and as expected.
To reproduce, repeat the same steps listed above, except when you reset the test ledger - do not load that program at genesis

no error here

Error being received
The error I receive when trying to upgrade the program loaded at genesis is:
Error: Deploying program failed: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: instruction changed executable accounts data; 2 log messages:
  Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
  Program BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111 failed: instruction changed executable accounts data

The solana program show output for the program loaded at genesis is as follows:
# solana program show AgVqLc7bKvnLL6TQnBMsMAkT18LixiW9isEb21q1HWUR -ul

Program Id: AgVqLc7bKvnLL6TQnBMsMAkT18LixiW9isEb21q1HWUR
Owner: BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111
ProgramData Address: 36QwUSVEfdLoXJ9n95UResaDM7PGFJ4QoYuxJb1vp1qm
Authority: nicktrLHhYzLmoVbuZQzHUTicd2sfP571orwo9jfc8c
Last Deployed In Slot: 0
Data Length: 196680 (0x30048) bytes
Balance: 1.37009688 SOL

Note: it is owned by the upgradable loader BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111

This is a bug! When loading upgradeable program accounts at genesis, the program-data account (36QwUSVEfdLoXJ9n95UResaDM7PGFJ4QoYuxJb1vp1qm) is marked executable, when it shouldn't be. https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/3692 will fix it

Ahh nice! Thanks for shipping a fix :)
